# Squarespace Header Injection Code

Tags: html, css, svg, code-injection, squarespace

I am using Squarespace for my portfolio. I recently was helped with animating my logo in SVG code. Now I have this code and I have no way of replacing my logo in the header with it. As you can see in my website:
http://www.christianadelvecchio.com/#welcome-christiana-delvecchio

My logo is to the left while my name is to the right of the logo. My name is clickable, but my logo is not. I believe this is because squarespace allows only one logo space in the header. While I was in college making my website, my professor injected custom css into the header so that my logo is to the left of my name.

```
.sqs-gallery-container{
background-color: rgba(175, 175, 175, .0);
}


.title-nav-wrapper { background:url(http://static.squarespace.com/static/52f29e06e4b0efe4bb40a01b/t/5320cb16e4b093b02ba9004e/1394658070983/logo.png) no-repeat; 
background-position: left center;
  margin-left: 10px;

}



#yui_3_10_1_1_1394658544560_1616{
margin-right: 100px;
}

a#top{width: 200px;
}

.site-title {
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-left: 50px;

width: 35%;
}
```

I want to replace my logo on the left with my SVG logo:

http://codepen.io/CaptnChristiana/full/ceygm/

But I have no idea how to inject it because if I replace the url in the current custom css code with my SVG url then nothing shows up. I think everything is reacting with one another so this makes it tricky. The gist is I want my logo to rotate 180 degrees when someone hovers on it, which I already have the code for, but the tricky part is injecting it into my website.

Any and all help is appreciated. (Sorry if this question is confusing)

Comment: Which template and version of Squarespace are you using?  Looks like Marquee and version 6?

Comment: Yes it is Marquee and version 6.